# Generalizing redundant code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have a table with multiple nullable foreign keys.

In my business logic I have to write different queries for each case, because the foreign key condition is different every time, like so:

```
var q1 = 
    from c in container.Stuff
    where c.fk1 = pk1id
    select c;

var q2 = 
    from c in container.Stuff
    where c.fk2 = pk2id
    select c;
```

Etc, this amounts to a lot of code duplication and a lot of extra stuff to think about (there are 10 of these fks in this table), so thats 40 {C,R,U,D}methods to keep track of, over different branches of the source.

Add to this the fact that this is repeateded in multiple tables and a maintenance nightmare is created.

I was wondering, is there some way to generalize this? Is there some way to make these queries more dynamic? If so, where should I start looking? I don't really see generics fitting in here, so is there some other construct to make this more abstract?

To make this more specific, some psuedo-like code to make this more concrete...

```
List<Stuff> ReadStuff(Type owningEntityType, int fkId)
{
     // Now I would somehow have to infer (perhaps by adding more info to the method signature) what column to put the where clause on and create an EF query based on that...

     // So how would I go from owningEntityType (or some textual description), to a 'real' field




 }
```

Comment: Do both queries return the same type of data? Also, are you using Entity Framework? Linq2Sql?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to dynamically create the EF query, and more specific the where clause. Is it possible to make that conditional?

Comment: Why aren't you using the corresponding navigation collection in the entity with the primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
public IQueryable<T> GenerateResultSet<T>(
       Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : BaseEntity
{
   return dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
var q1 = GenerateResultSet<Stuff>(c => c.fk1 == pkId);
var q2 = GenerateResultSet<Stuff2>(c => c.fk2 == pkId2);
```